# Dictionary for multiple lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like this:

```
list=[[21768L, u'2'], [1746L, u'2'], [2239L, u'2'],[2239L, u'2'], [1965L, u'2'],[1965L, u'2'], [2425L, u'1'], [2425L, u'1'],[2056L, u'1']]
```

How can I get the above list in the form of a dictionary like this:

```
d={u'1':[2425L,2],[2056L,1] , u'2': [21768L, 1],[1746L,1],[2239L,2],[1965L,2]}
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it has a special role in Python.

Comment: Your dictionary is invalid. You should elaborate more on the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
>>> L = [[21768L, u'2'], [1746L, u'2'], [2239L, u'2'], [2239L, u'2'], [1965L, u'2'],[1965L, u'2'], [2425L, u'1'], [2425L, u'1'], [2056L, u'1']]
>>> d = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
>>> for value, key in L:
        d[key][value] = d[key].get(value, 0) + 1


>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, 
            {u'1': OrderedDict([(2425L, 2), (2056L, 1)]), 
             u'2': OrderedDict([(21768L, 1), (1746L, 1), (2239L, 2), (1965L, 2)])})
```

Comment: @user9986 sounds like you might be getting variable names mixed up. `list` is a builtin in python, try changing the name first

Comment: @user9986 You would have to change the loop to go `for x in L:` and then do a check(`if not x: raise Exception # or whatever` before unpacking in the body. Alternatively you can use `for value, key in itertools.ifilter(None, L)`(or just `filter(None, L) on Python 3` which will get rid of empty lists(`[]`) as you iterate through.

Comment: @user9986 yeah or just do: `for x in L: try: value, key = x except: # error here do something`

Answer (score 9):

Use a `defaultdict` and a `Counter`, both from the `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = defaultdict(Counter)

for value, key in yourlist:
    d[key].update([value])
```

This gives you slightly different structure:

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {u'1': Counter({2425L: 2, 2056L: 1}), u'2': Counter({1965L: 2, 2239L: 2, 21768L: 1, 1746L: 1})})
```

but can be massaged to something closer to what you are looking for with:

```
d = {key: value.most_common() for key, value in d.iteritems()}
```

which gives:

```
{u'1': [(2425L, 2), (2056L, 1)], u'2': [(1965L, 2), (2239L, 2), (21768L, 1), (1746L, 1)]}
```